# Optional date input in a datetime field using django forms

Tags: python, django

```
class Pasthistory(models.Model):
    """
        To store Work Experience of the Employee.
        As of now no restriction on number of Past histories.
    """

    EMPLOYER_TYPES =(
        ("IND","Individual"),
        ("COR","Corporate"),
        )
    SLAB_CHOICES = (
        ('H', 'Hourly'),
        ('W', 'Weekly'),
        ('M', 'Monthly'),
    )
    # Choices for gender
    salary_slab         = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=SLAB_CHOICES,default='M')
    employee_id         = models.ForeignKey(Employee,verbose_name="employee id")
    worked              = models.ForeignKey(Jobs,verbose_name="job",default=0,null=True,blank=True)
    experience          = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Experience in years",null=True,blank=True,default=0)
    experience_mon      = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Experience in months",null=True,blank=True,default=0)
    started_from        = models.DateField()
    worked_till         = models.DateField()
    employer_type       = models.CharField(max_length=3,choices=EMPLOYER_TYPES,default="COR")
    company_name        = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True,blank=True)
    name_boss           = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)
    phone               = models.CharField(max_length=11,null=True,blank=True ,validators=[RegexValidator(regex='^\d{10}$', message='Length has to be 10 digits for mobile number or 11 digits for landline numbers', code='Invalid number')])
    email               = models.EmailField(null=True,blank=True)
    work_description    = models.TextField(max_length=255,null=True,blank=True)
    salary_drawn        = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True,blank=True)
    reason_for_leaving  = models.TextField(max_length=500,null=True,blank=True)


class exp_form(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Pasthistory
        exclude = ['employee_id']
        css_class   =  "form-control"
        select_class = 'form-control m-bot15'
        widgets = {
                    'worked'            :   forms.Select(       attrs   =   {'class'    :  select_class}),
                    'started_from'      :   forms.TextInput(    attrs   =   {'class'    :   css_class,'placeholder':'YYYY-MM-DD or MM/DD/YYYY'}),
                    'worked_till'       :   forms.TextInput(    attrs   =   {'class'    :   css_class,'placeholder':'YYYY-MM-DD or MM/DD/YYYY'}),
                    'salary_slab'       :   forms.Select(   attrs   =   {'class'    :   select_class}),
                    'employer_type'     :   forms.RadioSelect(),
                    'company_name'      :   forms.TextInput(    attrs   =   {'class'    :   css_class}),
                    'name_boss'         :   forms.TextInput(    attrs   =   {'class'    :   css_class}),
                    'experience'      :   forms.TextInput(    attrs   =   {'class'    :   css_class}),
                    'experience_mon'         :   forms.TextInput(    attrs   =   {'class'    :   css_class}),
                    'phone'             :   forms.TextInput(    attrs   =   {'class'    :   css_class,'placeholder':"Enter the phone number"}),
                    'email'             :   forms.TextInput(    attrs   =   {'class'    :   css_class,'placeholder':"Enter the email id"}),
                    'work_description'  :   forms.Textarea(     attrs   =   {'class'    :   css_class,'placeholder':'What all responsibilities did you perform at the job?'}),
                    'salary_drawn'      :   forms.TextInput(    attrs   =   {'class'    :   css_class}),
                    'reason_for_leaving':   forms.Textarea(     attrs   =   {'class'    :css_class,'placeholder':'Why did you leave / terminated from the job?'}),
        }

        def clean_worked_till(self):
            if self.cleaned_data['worked_till'] <= self.cleaned_data['started_from']:
                raise forms.ValidationError((u'Worked till has to be greater than Started from'))
            return self.cleaned_data['worked_till']
```

I want to take only the month and year as input from the front end and store it into the model. How can it be done through django forms?

Would it be required to append a day to the input before storing it in the model?

Comment: What is going on with the spacing in your post.